# mapping summation in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

## Target

I would like to compute a summmation using `map` function .

By using the follwoing sample data:

```
X = [[2,3,4,5,6],[1,4,5,3,5]]
Y = [8.5,9.6]
```

This is what I got for the moment:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[2,3,4,5,6],[1,4,5,3,5]])
Y = np.array([8.5,9.6])
summation = X[0].dot(Y[0]) + X[1].dot(Y[1])
```

or

```
summation = np.sum(X.T * Y, axis=-1)
```

## EDIT: Performance comparison

```
t0 = time.time()
print sum(map(lambda x: x*Y[np.where(X==x)[0][0]], X))
t1= time.time()-t0
print t1
0.000971078872681

t0 = time.time()
print X[0].dot(Y[0]) + X[1].dot(Y[1])
t1= time.time()-t0
print t1
0.000860929489136   
t0 = time.time()
print X.T.dot(Y)
t1= time.time()-t0
print t1
0.000858068466187 

t0 = time.time()
print np.sum(X.T * Y, axis=-1)
t1= time.time()-t0
print t1
0.000848054885864

t0 = time.time()
print summation(X,Y)
t1= time.time()-t0
print t1
0.00386810302734
```

The fastest solution was `summation with map function` followed by `np.sum`, the slowest was `map` function as well.

Comment: Your equation and sample data does not match. Equation shows two rank 1 tensors (aka vectors) and looks like a simple dot product while in the data `X` is a rank 2 tensor (aka matrix). Also, why would you want to use `map` while also using `numpy`?

Comment: @Ignacio Vergara Kausel . I Ereased the formula, I was wondering a new whay to do it by using map. For academic use and performance comparison.

Comment: To be fair, think you should be benchmarking on larger datasets.

Comment: Seriously, try this on 1000x1000 lists and you’ll see the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try this one too, although this is not the "cleanest" way of doing it:

```
X = np.array([[2,3,4,5,6],[1,4,5,3,5]])
Y = np.array([8.5,9.6])

def summation(X, Y):
    return sum(map(lambda x, y: x*y, X, Y))

print(summation(X,Y))
```

The result is :

```
[ 26.6  63.9  82.   71.3  99. ]
```

Answer (score 2):

A single `dot` call should be enough.

```
X.T.dot(Y)
array([ 26.6,  63.9,  82. ,  71.3,  99. ])
```

Which gives you the same result as the other two methods described. I'll wager this is faster than any `map` solution you could dream up (even though it'd make no sense to use here).

Comment: thats another way, thank you, but with map function how could by designed the function?

Comment: @PeCaDe Python map? You really can't, and I wouldn't recommend you doing so.

Comment: OK, it was to try the fastest way, to apply it in some parallel processing

Comment: @PeCaDe Good news! `X.T.dot(Y)` is probably the fastest method you'll ever see, bar none. I guarantee, or your money back.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is an elegant way, but it uses the map function

```
sum(map(lambda x: x*Y[np.where(X==x)[0][0]], X))
array([ 26.6,  63.9,  82. ,  71.3,  99. ])
```

Comment: You did it, I will edit to compare the performance. @COLDSPEED did a great job as well.

Comment: Awesome !
Interesting results :) 
All the best with this